# Cannot Stop window.setInterval()

Tags: javascript, ajax

I cannot seem to get this window.setInterval to stop.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    id = window.setInterval(updateReportStatus, 500);

    function updateReportStatus (){
        var url = "{{url_for('task_results', taskId=taskInfo.ID)}}"; 

        $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               url: url,
               success: function(data){
                    console.log('AJAX call is successful.')

                    if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data !== null && data !== 'waiting'){
                        data = JSON.parse (data)
                        //console.log(data)
                        var numberGaps = data.processedData.numberGaps
                        console.log(numberGaps)
                        var pie = data.processedData.completeness.completenessPie
                        console.log(pie)
                        var seriesData = data.processedData.processedTimeSeriesData
                        $('#dataCompleteness').append('<p>' + numberGaps + '<p>')
                        stop_query(); 
                        }

                    }// End of success function 

                }); //End of Ajax call 

            } //End of Polling function

        });
        function stop_query(){
                console.log('Stopping the following query........')
                console.log(id)
                window.clearInterval(id); 
        }
```

Here are the changes I made, which seem to be working. Changed window.setInterval() variable name from 'id' to 'myPoller'. Also set variable 'myPoller' to null after stop_query() function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var myPoller = window.setInterval(updateReportStatus, 5000);

    function updateReportStatus (){
        var  url = "{{url_for('task_results', taskId=taskInfo.ID)}}"; 

    $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: url,
           success: function(data){
                console.log('AJAX call is successful.')

                if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data !== null && data !== 'waiting'){
                    data = JSON.parse (data)
                    //console.log(data)
                    var numberGaps = data.processedData.numberGaps
                    console.log(numberGaps)
                    var pie = data.processedData.completeness.completenessPie
                    console.log(pie)
                    var seriesData = data.processedData.processedTimeSeriesData
                    $('#dataCompleteness').append('<p>' + numberGaps + '<p>')
                    stop_query(myPoller); 
                    myPoller = null
                    }

                }// End of success function 

            }); //End of Ajax call 

        } //End of Polling function

    });
    function stop_query(myPollerID){
            console.log('Stopping the following query........')
            console.log(myPollerID)
            window.clearInterval(myPollerID);

        }
```

Comment: What `console.log(id)` shows ?

Comment: console.log(id) shows 1.

Comment: Try declaring ìd`as a local variable using `var id = window.setInterval(updateReportStatus, 500);' I would also suggest to rename the variable, because **id** is quite common.
Also you may have race conditions in your stop_query method due to multiple invocations after ajax completition. Set id to null after clearing the interval and check if id is not null before clearing it.

Comment: The `id` variable is inside `document.ready` 's scope, and the stop function is outside the scope of `document.ready`, so it doesn't have access to `id`. Move the `stop_query` function ***inside*** the `document.ready` function.

Comment: @adeneo `id` seems to be an implicit global, and `stop_query` is global too.

Comment: @Teemu - indeed, didn't notice that, so I guess we have to test it then -> https://jsfiddle.net/v1qcfq33/

Comment: And it can't be reproduced, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MathewB.

Answer (score 1):

Your **stop_query** function cant use the local declared variable **id**. You have to assign your interval to an variable the **stop_query** function can "see".

This Code output ilustrate that one outsite declared function canot assign an local variable:

```js
//Global Counter Var:
var x = 0;

(function(){
  var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    var message = document.getElementById("message");
  var localVar = setInterval(incrementX, 700);

  function incrementX(){
      x++;
        console.log(x);
        counter.innerHTML = x;
        if(x === 10){
          message.innerHTML = "Uncaught ReferenceError: localVar is not defined"
          stopInteval();
        }
    }
})();

//this function cant use localVar!
function stopInteval(){
 clearInterval(localVar);
}
```

```css
#message{
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<pre>Counting until 10 is reached...</pre>
<p id="counter"></p>
<pre id="message"></pre>
```

**Solution:**
Move your local variable outside the function:

```js
//Global Counter Var:
var x = 0;
var localVar

(function(){
  var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    var message = document.getElementById("message");
  localVar = setInterval(incrementX, 200);

  function incrementX(){
      x++;
        console.log(x);
        counter.innerHTML = x;
        if(x === 10){
          message.innerHTML ="It worked!";
          stopInteval();
        }
    }
})();

function stopInteval(){
 clearInterval(localVar);
}
```

```html
<pre>Counting until 10 is reached...</pre>
<p id="counter"></p>
<pre id="message"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first: use `var` keyword to declare all new variables in your code.
Secondly, dispose the related logic blocks within `$( document ).ready(function() {` when using `JQuery` library:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var IntId = window.setInterval(updateReportStatus, 500);

    function updateReportStatus (){
        var url = "{{url_for('task_results', taskId=taskInfo.ID)}}"; 

        $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               url: url,
               success: function(response){
                    console.log('AJAX call is successful.')

                    if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data !== null && data !== 'waiting'){
                        var data = JSON.parse(response);
                        //console.log(data)
                        var numberGaps = data.processedData.numberGaps;
                        console.log(numberGaps)
                        var pie = data.processedData.completeness.completenessPie;
                        console.log(pie)
                        var seriesData = data.processedData.processedTimeSeriesData;
                        $('#dataCompleteness').append('<p>' + numberGaps + '<p>');
                        stop_query(); 
                    }

                }// End of success function 

         }); //End of Ajax call 

    } //End of Polling function
    function stop_query(){
            console.log('Stopping the following query........')
            console.log(IntId)
            window.clearInterval(IntId); 
    }

});
```